# How to update my Firebase references after upgrading to Firebase 3.2.1 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am updating my iOS app written in Swift(v2.2) to use Firebase 3.2.1. After updating CocoaPods, and then upgrading to Firebase 3.2.1 and doing a pod install with the following pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'myapp' do

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'Google/SignIn'

end

target 'myappTests' do

end

target 'myappUITests' do

end
```

I keep getting the error: **use of unresolved identifier 'Firebase'** in my code when trying to define the Firebase references as follows:

```
private var _BASE_REF = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)")
private var _USER_REF = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)/sales")
private var _USER_UID_REF = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)/sales/numb")
```

I have not been able to find clear instructions on how to update these references with the new Firebase version, please help. Thanks!

**Note:** BASE_URL is a constant defined as follows in a separate swift file.

```
let BASE_URL = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

**Note 2:** Firebase version details below:

```
Using Bolts (1.7.0)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.13.1)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.13.1)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.13.1)
Using Firebase (3.2.1)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0)
Using FirebaseDatabase (3.0.1)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.6)
Using Google (3.0.3)
Using GoogleAppUtilities (1.1.1)
Using GoogleAuthUtilities (2.0.1)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.1)
Using GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.1)
Using GoogleSignIn (4.0.0)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.1)
Using GoogleUtilities (1.3.1)
```

**UPDATE**
Furthermore, I have now declared my references as indicated below. However, one of my current references which used to work with the older Firebase version returns a current user and it is now giving me the error **use of undeclared type Firebase**. Please advise how should this be updated to conform to the new version? All of this code was obtained from the Firebase documentation pertaining to the old version. I have not been able to find similar declarations in the documentation for the new version. Hence the question. Thanks.

```
private var _BASE_REF = BASE_URL
private var _USER_REF = BASE_URL.child("user")
private var _USER_UID_REF = BASE_URL.child("user/uid")
var CURRENT_USER_REF: Firebase {
        let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String

        let currentUser = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_REF)").childByAppendingPath("user").childByAppendingPath(userID)

        return currentUser!
    }
```

Comment: `BASE_URL.child("YOUR_CHILD_PATH")` like `BASE_URL.child("sales/numb")`

Comment: And for the unresolved error: you should import in your bridging-header like `@import Firebase;`

Comment: thank you!! one last thing I forgot to mention, right below declaring the references I have something like this:     How should I modify these?                                                     var BASE_REF: Firebase {
        return _BASE_REF
    }
    
    var USER_REF: Firebase {
        return _USER_REF
    }

Comment: Just access like this `_USER_UID_REF = BASE_URL.child("sales/numb")`

Comment: In more detailed: Declare your `BASE_URL` as constant somewhere which is publicly accessible like `let BASE_URL = FIRDatabase.database().reference()`. 
And in your class, declare below: 
`private let _BASE_REF = BASE_URL
    private let _USER_UID_REF = BASE_URL.child("sales/numb")
    private let _USER_REF = BASE_URL.child("sales")`

Comment: @Santosh Please see my UPDATE. I need to be able to return my reference as a variable to return the current user. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `var CURRENT_USER_REF: FIRDatabaseReference {
        let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String
        let currentUser = _BASE_REF.child("user").child(userID)
        return currentUser
    }`. Please note that `Firebase` has changed its APIs in recent updates, you should follow the official document for reference. The `init` with `url` is not available anymore, so all you need is `FIRDatabaseReference` as reference. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/

Comment: in reference to your comment about importing the bridging-header, my understanding from the documentation is that for Swift I need to add use_frameworks! to my pod file instead of importing the bridging header. Did this change for Firebase 3.0? Do I now need the bridging header anyways?

Comment: Where did I mention to import bridging header?? You should import Firebase within bridging header. Keep your pod as it is.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your guidance!